# DISTINCT for foreach

Tags: php

```
<?php

$array = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'eee');

foreach($array as $a){
   echo $a;
}
```

Is possible use some like DISTINCT for foreach? I would like show each values only one, without repeat. How is the best way for this?

http://codepad.org/FZQNEBeK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `array_unique()` gets pretty bad when you have large arrays. You would be better off with `$uniques =  array_flip(array_flip($array))`.

Comment: Could you please tell why `array_unique()` gets bad when you have large array?

Comment: @Starx , i am quite bad at C, so you can [check the implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.3/ext/standard/array.c#L2769) yourself. But this is how I understand `array_unique()` the process : copy the original array >> sort the data in that copy >> remove the duplicates from copy >> return the copy

Answer (score 10):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
$array = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'eee');
$result = array_unique($array);
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/BPdZQiKl)